# Select query for a tuple of values in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

Objects has values like:-

```
 valA   valB
  1      1
  1      3
  1      4
  1      5
  2      3
  2      6
  3      7
```

Lets say the distinct no of values for valA is m and valB is n. (m<

```
  Objects.each do|var|
      X.where("a = ? AND b = ?",var.valA,var.valB).first
```

This fires a query for each of the combination of values of valA and valB.

I want to fire one query to get all the records and process them. How should I do that?

PS: Worst case I can fire m queries, one for each valA and use IN query for valB values.

**Edit** :- Currently, one query will be fired for each combination of valA and valB(7 over here), and each object(of X) will be processed. I want to fire only a single query (using a tuple of values for valA and valB or some other method), in order to get all the objects from X.

Answer (score 1):

```
X.select("MIN(id)").group("valA, ValB")
```

Comment: Don't I need to create a list of valA and valB(sort of a tuple) and fire a query to get me all the records from X. What is the MIN(id) part doing?